# How to translate the mathematical term "dictionnaire des suivants et des précédents" in English?

Tags: translation, mathematics, terminology

There is a lack of references for graph theory translation from French to English, yet if you have some, let me know, I would appreciate it.

I always have some difficulties to translate these technical terms, how do you translate in English:

> dictionnaire des suivants et des précédents

which is an array telling for each vertex what is its following vertex or vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first, *dictionnaire* could certainly be translated as *array*, but under some circumstances (principally computer programming) it might be better to translate as *dictionary*. In programming languages, a distinction is sometimes made between a dictionary, which is a list of key-value pairs, and an array, which is simply an ordered list.

Next, I think it is important to keep in mind that your graph is presumably directed. For an undirected graph, it would be meaningless to refer to the *suivants* vs the *précédents*. In this case, some sources refer to *incoming neighbors* vs. *outgoing neighbors*. However, *predecessors* and *successors*  might be the best way of referring to this, as indicated in Wikipedia's [glossary of graph theory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_graph_theory)

So I would write *array of predecessors and successors*, or *dictionary of predecessors and successors*, depending on the context. If there is not potential for confusion, it might be acceptable to reference an *array of neighbors*.

It is worth noting that a mathematician would mostly likely speak instead of the *adjacency matrix*. Since you are asking a question about graph theory, you may already know what an adjacency matrix is, but if you don't, it is a matrix (essentially a two-layer-deep array) that represents the directed edges between two points. I am sure that for sparse graphs, this would be an inefficient representation for computing, but in any theoretical work, I would assume this would be the default.

Answer (score 1):

In computer science, that would probably be referred to as a "map" or "dictionary" between vertices. Alternatively, the structure as a whole sounds a lot like a "graph", either directed (that is, it matters whether it's A→B or B→A) or undirected (probably directed, since it sounds like it does matter), and either cyclic (A→B→A is permissible) or acyclic. Generally, computer science borrows a lot of terminology from math, especially graph theory, so that should be fine.